# email a zipped version of active workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I want to email a zipped copy of my workbook using Outlook.
How do I extend the macro below, so that it attached a zipped workbook?

```
Sub EmailWorkbook()

Dim OL As Object, EmailItem As Object
Dim Wb As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set EmailItem = OL.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook
Wb.Save
With EmailItem
    .Subject = "COB" & Format(Range("yesterday"), "ddMMMyy")
    '.Body = ""
    .To = "somewhere@maildomain.com"
    '.Cc = ""
    '.Bcc = ""
    .Importance = olImportanceNormal
    .Attachments.Add Wb.FullName
    .Display
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set Wb = Nothing
Set OL = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Ron has covered it in his site. See this link http://www.rondebruin.nl/windowsxpzip.htm

Comment: There is another way using Winzip if you are interested?

Comment: Thank you got it working from that link. Cheers.

Comment: Gr8 :) Then why not paste the code that you arrived at and accept that as an answer? Just to let you know that you can answer you own question (it is even highly recommended See this link http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking) and accept it. It will help other people who have the same problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub NewZip(sPath)
'Create empty Zip File
'Changed by keepITcool Dec-12-2005
    If Len(Dir(sPath)) > 0 Then Kill sPath
    Open sPath For Output As #1
    Print #1, Chr$(80) & Chr$(75) & Chr$(5) & Chr$(6) & String(18, 0)
    Close #1
End Sub


Function bIsBookOpen(ByRef szBookName As String) As Boolean
' Rob Bovey
    On Error Resume Next
    bIsBookOpen = Not (Application.Workbooks(szBookName) Is Nothing)
End Function


Function Split97(sStr As Variant, sdelim As String) As Variant
'Tom Ogilvy
    Split97 = Evaluate("{""" & _
                       Application.Substitute(sStr, sdelim, """,""") & """}")
End Function


Sub Zip_File_Or_Files()
    Dim strDate As String, DefPath As String, sFName As String
    Dim oApp As Object, iCtr As Long, I As Integer
    Dim FName, vArr, FileNameZip

    DefPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
    If Right(DefPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        DefPath = DefPath & "\"
    End If

    strDate = Format(Now, " dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")
    FileNameZip = DefPath & "MyFilesZip " & strDate & ".zip"

    'Browse to the file(s), use the Ctrl key to select more files
    FName = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xl*), *.xl*", _
                    MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Select the files you want to zip")
    If IsArray(FName) = False Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        'Create empty Zip File
        NewZip (FileNameZip)
        Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        I = 0
        For iCtr = LBound(FName) To UBound(FName)
            vArr = Split97(FName(iCtr), "\")
            sFName = vArr(UBound(vArr))
            If bIsBookOpen(sFName) Then
                MsgBox "You can't zip a file that is open!" & vbLf & _
                       "Please close it and try again: " & FName(iCtr)
            Else
                'Copy the file to the compressed folder
                I = I + 1
                oApp.Namespace(FileNameZip).CopyHere FName(iCtr)

                'Keep script waiting until Compressing is done
                On Error Resume Next
                Do Until oApp.Namespace(FileNameZip).items.Count = I
                    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
                Loop
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        Next iCtr

        MsgBox "You find the zipfile here: " & FileNameZip
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Download and install [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) then modify your existing code as follows:

```
Sub EmailWorkbook()
    Dim OL As Object, EmailItem As Object
    Dim xlWbName As String, xlWbPath As String, ext As String

    'Set xlWb file name and path
    xlWbName = "ENTER FILE NAME HERE"
    xlWbPath = "C:\ENTER\FILE\FOLDER\HERE"
    ext = "ENTER FILE EXTENSION HERE"

    Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set EmailItem = OL.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    'Make sure file xlWbName.ext is closed or close it before running the next line
    Shell "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" & " a -tzip """ & xlWbPath & "\" & xlWbName & ".zip"" """ & xlWbPath & "\" & xlWbName & ext & """"

    With EmailItem
        .Subject = "Enter subject here"
        '.Body = ""
        .To = "somewhere@maildomain.com"
        '.Cc = ""
        '.Bcc = ""
        .Importance = olImportanceNormal
        .Attachments.Add xlWbPath & "\" & xlWbName & ".zip"
        .Display
    End With

    Set OL = Nothing
End Sub
```

I tested the above code and it successfully attached the zipped file.